# How can I keep field data after validating false in flask wtform?

Tags: forms, flask

I am new to flask and don't know how to keep field data after a failing post.

Thanks for your helps ^_^.

Example:

views.py:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', ])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form) 
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            # blabla...
            return redirect('/')
        else: # validate false
            # how to keep field data in new page?
            return render_template('index.html', form=form) # it failed
```

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because I implement my own html form fields, in order to solve the problem, I should write template like this:

index.html:

```
<form ...>
    {{ form.fieldname(class_='form-control', placeholder='hint') }}
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer more please? I am having a similar issue but I don't understand your resolution. I lose data in other fields when the form validate fails.

Comment: For example, there is an input field `username`, you should use `{{ form.username(class_='form-control', placeholder='hint') }}` in your template to generate a form field. I remember that `{{ form.username.data }}` cannot get the user input data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheriting your Form class from wtforms.Form, inherit it from flask_wtf.FlaskForm

For example, Replace this

```
from wtforms import Form
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    #fields...
```

With this

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    #fields...
```